# Get data between this month and the next 3 - MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to get some data using a MySQL statement, between the current month to the next 3 months and it doesn't work.

What I would like to do is to get all the date from `myTable` where the month from the column `expiration_date` is between the current month and the next 3 months.

In other words, all the data from `myTable` from now to the next 3 months.

Here is my statement:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable
WHERE MONTH(expiration_date) BETWEEN MONTH(CURDATE()) AND INTERVAL 3 MONTH
```

It doesn't work in phpmyadmin / xampp where I test the query before writing the PHP code.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with PHP or XAMPP.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM myTable 
WHERE MONTH(expiration_date) BETWEEN MONTH(CURDATE()) AND  DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 3 MONTH)
```

For add 3 month to current date use this

```
DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 3 MONTH)
```